# Check Pixel of transparency in Win 8 RT App

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, transparency, pixel

How can I check the pixel in an image of their content? I want to know which pixel is transparency and which pixel not. I found the Bitmap.GetPixel() Method but it didn't work in a Win8 RT App. How can I do this in C#?

My Image is in a ImageBrush like this:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="myImage" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0" TranslateY="495"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/myImage.png"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
```

Comment: there are many different types of images, specify the class

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WriteableBitmap` instead of the default `BitmapImage` as the `ImageSource` and then access its `PixelBuffer` property, call `AsStream()` on it and find the pixel you are looking for. Each pixel has a byte for each of the RGBA values, though I don't recall currently which is the order of these - you'd need to look it up. The `A` byte is the alpha value. 255 is fully opaque while 0 is fully transparent.

Here's a sample (uses Windows 8.1's `RenderTargetBitmap` instead of `WriteableBitmap` so I don't need to include a transparent image):

```
<Page
    x:Class="App44.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App44"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid
            x:Name="SourceGrid"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            SizeChanged="SourceGrid_OnSizeChanged">
            <Ellipse
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                StrokeThickness="20"
                Stroke="Red">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush
                        StartPoint="0,0"
                        EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop
                            Offset="0"
                            Color="Green"/>
                        <GradientStop
                            Offset=".25"
                            Color="Green" />
                        <GradientStop
                            Offset=".75"
                            Color="Blue" />
                        <GradientStop
                            Offset="1"
                            Color="Blue" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
        <Image
            x:Name="TargetImage"
            Stretch="None"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            PointerMoved="TargetImage_OnPointerMoved" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="ResultTextBlock"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            FontSize="28"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And code behind:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace App44
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private RenderTargetBitmap rtb;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void SourceGrid_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await this.rtb.RenderAsync(this.SourceGrid);
            this.TargetImage.Source = this.rtb;
        }

        private async void TargetImage_OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pixels = await this.rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
            var stream = pixels.AsStream();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.TargetImage);
            stream.Seek((long)(point.Position.Y) * this.rtb.PixelWidth * 4 + (long)(point.Position.X) * 4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte b = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
            byte g = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
            byte r = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
            byte a = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
            //var color = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
            this.ResultTextBlock.Text = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}, is transparent: {4}", a, r, g, b, a == 0);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know a example where the writablebitmap is in use?

Comment: Sure, look [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Imaging/WriteableBitmapDarkenExtension.cs), [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Imaging/IBufferExtensions.cs) and [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Imaging/ColorExtensions.cs)

Comment: How can I convert image file in the assets folder to WriteableBitmap?

Comment: Definitely and hopefully yes :) Get the File using that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync.aspx and everything else is juste the same as you would do with a regular file stored on your hard drive.

Comment: I think to use this i must add the WinRT XAML Toolkit files. I prefer a solution with no external components.

Comment: There are a few files that I referenced that help with it. You don't need to add all the files from the toolkit.